# Why do White Walkers wear clothes? Or why were they once (nearly) naked?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

White Walkers in the first and second season were nearly naked.

This guy from the start of the first season wears a raggy loin cloth, a vambrace, and boots. His three brothers in the background wear similar loin cloths and nothing on their chests.

[image]

This walker from the end of the second season has a vambrace on his forearm and not much else.

[image]

Later in the series, they are wearing clothes and even armor.

Fast-forward a few seasons to the Battle of Hardhome, and we see multiple walkers and the Night King all wearing clothes and armor. (Never guessed he was just a little vain enough to wear a decoration on his upper chest.)

[image]

We saw 4 walkers and the King in the Battle of the Tree all wearing armor.

[image]

**Why did they start wearing armor?** (Related questions: Why would they even care to wear clothes at all? They don't need clothing to protect them from blizzards. Do they make their own armor and clothes?)

I prefer answers from the book (even if the answer says the question is based on a false premise) more than answers from the TV series.

**Edit to add:** I am not asking about the wights, just the White Walkers and the Night King. I assume the wights and skeletons have whatever clothes they wore at the moment of re-animation and will wear those until the clothes are so shredded they fall off.

Comment: [They went shopping](http://67.media.tumblr.com/493b0c0ac31cc59067db50561394dc36/tumblr_nq1ckbr6RD1uyzmv8o1_1280.jpg)

Comment: @Aegon Thanks! That was hilarious!

Comment: Out of universe, it's cheaper to do guys in clothes with blue face makeup than it is to do CGI frost monsters.  While naked actors in the snow may turn blue without makeup, they will likely also charge you more for their acting.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think the [first time we see white walkers wearing armour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XhyLKJgd8Zw) is also the first time we see them after [Sam kills one with an obsidian dagger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mAfdHNjbYHU). I think before this, they were always sporting the "winter casual" skirts-and-bracers look. Maybe there was an off-screen "[This s*** just got real](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvqJ1mTkEuY). Put your obsidian-proof vests on, lads, and meet me by the baby-sacrificing table"

Comment: @Aegon Nice!  : ) In all fairness, in the show maybe they don't bother with armour when wandering the woods picking off the odd stray wildling or ranger - but when gearing up for a larger campaign - they get dressed.

Comment: @user568458 fwiw in the books the armor did not help against obsidian either.

Comment: As speculation, in the show i always took them starting to wear armor as a sign they are indeed intelligent and aware they are also preparing for war. As a few other comments have suggested

Comment: @Paul leave the actors enough time in the snow and you won't have to pay them anymore! :-D

Comment: @Aegon Link is dead

Comment: @Vahx Huh! Working for me. However [Here you go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq9dO.jpg), hosted on stack imgur now.

Comment: Winter is coming, so it makes sense they’ve been layering up. As a friend of mine suggested, everyone’s wondering what exactly the White Walkers want, when the answer is obvious: jackets. They want nice, warm jackets.

Comment: @paul That also explains why I'm S07E06 they didn't throw a spear into anyone on the pack in case they poke a hole in their jackets.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Since you have added the books tag, I will avoid the show heresy and answer this from the books.

#### What do Others aka White Walkers wear?

In books, others do not run around naked. They are dressed in a special magical armor which camouflages them into their surroundings.

From [wiki](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Others):

> "Had many talks with George. He told me of the ice swords, and **the
> reflective, camouflaging armor that picks up the images of the things
> around it like a clear, still pond**. He spoke a lot about what they
> were not, but what they were was harder to put into words."
>  <sub>-**Tommy Patterson** *(Comic book artist for the series)*</sub>

Also:

> A shadow emerged from the dark of the wood. It stood in front of
> Royce. Tall, it was, and gaunt and hard as old bones, with flesh pale
> as milk. **Its armor seemed to change color as it moved; here it was
> white as new-fallen snow, there black as shadow, everywhere dappled
> with the deep grey-green of the trees.** The patterns ran like
> moonlight on water with every step it took.
> <sub>AGOT -
> Prologue</sub>

So while we may not know what exactly do they wear due to reflective nature of their garb, we know they wear an armor so presumably some other garment underneath as well. Therefore, The idea that they run around naked or with minimal clothing is absurd.

As far as books are concerned, they always wear armor (Except maybe when it is a nice sunny day, then I presume they go sunbathing on the [Frozen shore](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Frozen_Shore)).

A depiction of Others from *The World of Ice and Fire* companion book:

[image]

#### Why did the Show depict them as a naturist club in the beginning?

[image]

Comment: Yes, I prefer an answer from the book over one from the tv show.

Comment: Given what you said here, I would much prefer the tv series portray the walkers wearing armor with shifting colors like moonlight dappled on water. It would have added to their eerieness of the Others.

Comment: @RichS Ideally yes but it would also cost some money in CGI. So I can see why D&D would rather ignore it and stall the regular armors too until White Walkers start playing a more prominent role in the show.

Comment: To answer your rhetorical question about why they made then more naked on the show. That's easy... it's HBO.

Comment: I imagine the first few episodes had to really hustle in terms of cash, because piloting a show, you know, people are reluctant to find new stuff.

Comment: `I will avoid the show heresy` And *that's* why I like you so much!

Comment: I assumed we were meeting higher and higher ranking Others as the show goes on...

Comment: @Liath The higher ranking ones get fancy clothes and the lower ones don't get even the basics? I won't stand for this injustice!!! Proletarians of the undead North unite, you have nothing to lose except your chains! :P

Comment: @Aegon think about it from a parent's perspective.  You buy armor for your little White Walker but he'll outgrow it by next winter.  No sir, you get armor when you earn it as an adult by killing a Crow! :)

Answer (score 0):

So of the two types, those who appear with very little clothing I guess have been in the ground dead for longer, maybe when the snows weren't as far south as they are now - this allowed their clothes to rot away - some of them are as you've noticed almost just skeletons as if the very flesh has rotted off their undead bones.

The same way, those who have died in the snow - they haven't rotted much at all (the two crows who came back and attacked were still fully clothed) and so they are clothed as zombies too. Along with these the wrights too have clothes and the full armour they apparently 'died' in. I presume they were brought back as wrights almost immediately hence there was no damage/rotting of clothing.

Comment: The others aren't dead. They are different type of life. A different species if you will.